# Filter remove NA string or value from tibble

Tags: r

Here I'm attempting to remove NA values from a tibble :

```
mc = as_tibble(c("NA" , NA , "ls", "test"))
mc <- filter(mc , is.na == TRUE)
```

But error is returned :

```
> mc = as_tibble(c("NA" , NA , "ls", "test"))
> mc <- filter(mc , is.na == TRUE)
Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
Evaluation error: comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types.
```

How to remove NA values from this tibble ?

Comment: `complete.cases` and `na.omit` would not work in this case. Those functions would keep the `"NA"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
library(tidyverse)

mc %>% 
  mutate(value = replace(value, value == "NA", NA)) %>% 
  drop_na()
```

Which gives:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 1
  value
  <chr>
1    ls
2  test
```

Second line replaces all `"NA"` to a real `<NA>`. Then the third line drops all `<NA>` values.

Comment: thanks, but I receive error : Error in function_list[[k]](value) : could not find function "drop_na" . mc %>% na.omit does the job

Comment: Apologies, `drop_na` is a function from the `tidyr` library, you will have to install or load this package. `na.omit` from the `stats` package would also work.

Comment: I'm loading the library : library(dplyr)

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to remove actual NA values:

```
library(dplyr)
filter(mc, !is.na(value))
```

Alternatively (this will check all columns, not just the specified column as above):

```
na.omit(mc)
```

If you want to remove both NA values, and values equaling the string "NA":

```
library(dplyr)
filter(mc, !is.na(value), !value == "NA")
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions given by @tyluRp and @danh work perfectly fine.

Just wanted to add another alternative solution with the advantages

- simpler code
- shorter - for the lazy ones like me :)

See this one-liner:

```
mc %>% replace(. == "NA", NA) %>% na.omit
```